# Should I have a privacy policy on my personal website?

Tags: privacy, website

Assuming I have a personal website that I maintain, without offering users the possibility to log in, nor giving them the option to post any content of their own, should I design a privacy policy?

The website would mainly be used as an online resume of sorts, mainly for personal purposes and intended only for companies that I'm applying to to view.

In such circumstances, the only "personal" information that I use from them are IP addreses that the server uses to keep an open connection with their computers (and even those, the server discards automatically once the connection closes, except for special cases when technical failures records these addresses in error logs).

Is it necessary for me to make such a policy just for mentioning this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are not collecting or using an private information, I don't see that such a policy is required, although you could post one if you choose to.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you another viewpoint on this topic:

You haven't told us anything about you or your project, this leaves out a lot of information that could influence the outcome of your question. Across the globe there are quite a few different privacy regimes to be found and therefore the answer is, as every so often in law, "it depends".

This is what the European Commission has to say regarding IP addresses: [yes, IP addresses are to be considered personal data](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/what-personal-data_en).

Even if you fall under another regime, it might still be good practice to inform about your practices, who you are and generally be transparent.